# How to remove vowels from a given string in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to remove vocals from a string in Prolog.

I've been looking for all the day for some help but all I could find is this.

```
deleteV([H|T],R):-member(H,[a,e,i,o,u]),deleteV(T,R),!.
deleteV([H|T],[H|R]):-deleteV(T,R),!.
deleteV([],[]).
```

which is not working for me.
I tested with SWI-Prolog

Could someone guide me to be able to do this?

Thanks million times!

Comment: Can you give a sample call that is not working?

Comment: This is the output.. https://imgur.com/a/xyeskRS , do I do something wrong?

Comment: That's a list with one element, the list should be `[a, b, c, d,e, f, g]`

Comment: Oh yea, you are right!  Thank you so much for opening my eyes :D it's funny how blind I can be. Sorry for that.   but beside that I have to make vowels uppercase characters and consonants lowercase characters. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like this (assuming that the string contains only lower-case ASCII letters):

```
remove_vowels( []     , []    ) .
remove_vowels( [C|Cs] ,    L  ) :- vowel(c), !, remove_vowels(Cs,L) .
remove_vowels( [C|Cs] , [C|L] ) :-              remove_vowels(Cs,L) .

vowel(a).
vowel(e).
vowel(i).
vowel(o).
vowel(u).
```

Answer (score 0):

DCG works :

```
vowel(a).
vowel(e).
vowel(i).
vowel(o).
vowel(u).
vowel(y).

remove_vowels([A|T]) --> {vowel(A)}, remove_vowels(T).
remove_vowels([A|T]) --> {\+vowel(A)}, [A], remove_vowels(T).
remove_vowels([]) --> [].
```

For example :

```
?- string_chars("i like prolog", L), phrase(remove_vowels(L), R, []).
L = [i, ' ', l, i, k, e, ' ', p, r|...],
R = [' ', l, k, ' ', p, r, l, g] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that your code, as is, works in SWI-Prolog:

```
?- [user].
|: deleteV([H|T],R):-member(H,[a,e,i,o,u]),deleteV(T,R),!.
|: deleteV([H|T],[H|R]):-deleteV(T,R),!.
|: deleteV([],[]).
% user://1 compiled 0.00 sec, 3 clauses

?- atom_chars(an_Atom_with_Mixed_case,Cs), deleteV(Cs,D).
Cs = [a, n, '_', 'A', t, o, m, '_', w|...],
D = [n, '_', 'A', t, m, '_', w, t, h|...].
```

Also, note that [what you're after](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=subtract/3) is already available in library([lists](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists)):

```
?- atom_chars(an_Atom_with_Mixed_case,Cs), subtract(Cs,[a,e,i,o,u],D).
Cs = [a, n, '_', 'A', t, o, m, '_', w|...],
D = [n, '_', 'A', t, m, '_', w, t, h|...].
```

Now you can compare your implementation with that of SWI-Prolog. If you're running the IDE, try

```
?- edit(subtract).
```